# What is the relationship between the Maximal Clique problem and the Maximal Independent Set problem?

Tags: graph-theory

What is the relationship between the maximal clique problem and the maximal independent set problem? How is it possible to use an algorithm that solves one of the problems to solve the other?

Comment: Hint: complement

Answer (score 0):

Like @RobPratt said... if you have a graph with a given clique set, meaning that every vertex is pair-wise adjacent with each other. Then taking the complement of that graph means, that if two vertices had a common edge, in the original graph, they won`t be connected by an edge anymore in the complement graph and vice versa. Meaning that, if you have clique, you know that every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex in the set and if you would take the complement of the same graph, by the definition of the complement graph, you know that those vertices won´t be adjacent to each other. Hence, you have an independent set. So if you have a maximum clique in a given graph, you have also the maximum independent set in its complement.